# How can I create an array from the results of 2 queries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to create an array from the results of 2 queries, and send it all together to front-end, but I'm stuck to the point where I need to push the results of the second query to the array, I tried to do it using `array_push` but doesn't work.

Let's say we have this example, and I need to include the results of `$query2` to `$return_arr`

Any ideas?

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

include "config.php";

$return_arr = array();


$query1 = "SELECT * FROM balance WHERE class='income' ORDER BY id DESC";
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM balance WHERE class='expense' ORDER BY id DESC";


$result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$query1);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
    
    $id = $row['id'];
    $description = $row['description'];
    $date = $row['date'];
    $euro = $row['euro'];
    $who = $row['who'];
    $class = $row['class'];
    


    $return_arr[] = array("id_income" => $id,
                    "description_income" => $description,
                    "date_income" => $date,
                    "euro_income" => $euro,
                    "who_income" => $who,
                    "class_income" => $class
                    );


}


// Encoding array in JSON format
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM balance 
 WHERE class IN('income','expense') 
 ORDER 
    BY class
     , id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Like JS Bach answer. But maybe you could speed up performance by mention the column's name.

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM balance WHERE class IN ('income','expense') ORDER BY class, id DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of **OR** operator

```
$query = SELECT * FROM balance WHERE class = "income" OR class = "expense" ORDER BY class, id DESC;

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$array = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Your fetched records will already be in an array format in **$array**

This can be more effective when dealing with tables having records in 1000s of rows